# Can you tweak GAE's memcache timeout?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, objectify

we're experiencing repetitive memcache errors. I see a "LogAndContinueErrorHandler" so requests don't fail but they take an awful amount of time to be fullfilled.
Is there any way to force a maximum response time for memcache (something like 50ms?).

> com.google.appengine.api.memcache.LogAndContinueErrorHandler
>   handleServiceError: Service error in memcache
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache
>   getIdentifiables: exception getting multiple keys     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler.handleApiProxyException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:76)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.absorbParentException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:120)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.handleParentException(FutureWrapper.java:53)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:92)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:28)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.getIdentifiables(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:61)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.getAll(EntityMemcache.java:215)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService.get(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:253)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService.get(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:216)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingDatastoreService.get(CachingDatastoreService.java:137)
>     at
>   siena.gae.GaePersistenceManager.get(GaePersistenceManager.java:2146)
>     at siena.core.batch.BaseBatch.get(BaseBatch.java:60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to do that in Python by setting the `deadline` parameter of the [`create_rpc`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_create_rpc) method.

For Java is less straightforward, because MemcacheService don't allow you to set an [`ApiConfig`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy.java&q=ApiConfig%20package%3agoogleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=445).

This [article](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/App-Engine-Java-API-call-hooks) shows you how to install API hook for the API package.

After that you should be able to override the deadline for the current API call by setting `com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.api_deadline_key` environment variable like the SDK does in [ApiProxy.java](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy.java#99)

Don't forget to restore it to it's previous value once the RPC call is fired.